# QGIS Advanced digitizing switch from Cartesian to Ellipse

Tags: qgis, digitizing, ellipse, cartesian

I´m trying to draw a line per length, but I need to enter the length in the Ellipse value.

Is there a way to switch the values in the length window in the advanced digitizing panel from Cartesian to Ellipsoid?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not supported at the moment:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30682